# Ngix - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

I have a Bad Gateway issue on a Ruby on Rails environment and I know absolutely nothing about Ruby. I am going to be running an app for a week and a half and had this app setup by a contracted whom is not available.

*Sorry if there is an answer somewhere already, everything I seen was for PHP environments and I need to solve this in 24 hours before we launch our campaign, so in a bit of panic situation.*

**The VPS it's running on:**

```
104.131.241.16 | http://invite.teachtomarket.com
Ruby on Rails on 14.04 (Nginx + Unicorn)
```

**What happened before it last**

I couldn't get into the server via FTP or SSH, so I reset the root password. I'm assuming this caused the issue because the site went down right after.

**Additional Information**

In case it matters, the domain is run through GoDaddy and with an A record pointing to the IP address.

**Update #1**

When I type "unicorn" using the command line this is what it tells me, no idea what it means:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'rack' (~> 1.5.2) - did find: [rack-1.4.5] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1295:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1284:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1284:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1266:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1298:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1284:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1284:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1266:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:54:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

**Updated 3:40 PM EST (Based on Talk with BroiSatse**

We were able to get the error from 502 to 504 Time-out.

In the process the `#APP_ROOT=/home/rails` was commented out, that has been fixed and now it's a 504 Gateway Time-out.

Comment: Check if unicorn is running.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but how do I do that? Speaking to a complete new here when it comes to anything not PHP.

Comment: There should be a file `config/unicorn.rb`. Find a line `pid 'some/path/to/pid/file'`. Check if the file exists, if it doesn't unicorn is not running. If it exists, check if the process with a number within this file exists with `ps -aux | grep <process_number>`. Finally if it is not running, you'll need to start it with `RAILS_ENV=production unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -D` from project root.

Comment: Inside the app there is a folder called `config/` with the file `unicorn.rb` in it. There is nothing within this file that has any pad to a pid.

Comment: Could you paste this file to your question?

Comment: I have, sorry my comment didn't come through where I said I pasted it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63697/discussion-between-broisatse-and-dvoutt).